# User is able to open the JavaFx application more than once

Tags: java, maven, javafx

- I devlop one javafx application.
- And i am deploying that application as native installer which is created with the help of javafx-maven-plugin.
- but after the application is install i am getting problem is that "User is able to open the application more than once".
- so there is any solution in program(code of application) or maven-plugin to run only single instance of application.

Comment: One way is to use a filelock, the other is to make your app send packets on some port and check if there is anything before launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a JUnique library, this helps the developer to restrict the instantiation of java class component. Please read the documentation -- [JUnique Documentation](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/junique/manual.php?PHPSESSID=iir5i5v74mtqp2bv7eo1euf3l6)